# how can i switch between two views using CATransition?

Tags: ios, uiview, swift, caanimation, catransition

I have implemented in my code today a CATransition of type cube,
as I seen here, CATransition can be added to self.view.layer,
so my first question is if I can use my CATransition for switching between viewControllers and not just UIViews?

if I can't do it, 
please look at this image:
http://up411.siz.co.il/up1/hnmim2mtjodt.png
as you can see, while the transition is in process, I see the same view of both faces of the cube,
I'd like it to be that one face presents view A and the other one presents view B

here is the code if needed :

```
self.view.layer.addAnimation(createTransition("Right"), forKey: "kCATransition")

func createTransition(side:String) -> CATransition{
    var transition = CATransition()
    transition.delegate = self
    transition.duration = 0.6
    transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: "easeInEaseOut")
    transition.type = "cube"
    transition.subtype = "from\(side)"

    return transition
}
```

Comment: Where is the difference to your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25605106/how-to-switch-views-in-catransition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the same transition to the view layer of the second view controller's view as well.

Apple documentation in the [Core Animation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/AdvancedAnimationTricks/AdvancedAnimationTricks.html):

> To perform a transition animation, you create a CATransition object and add it to the **layers** involved in the transition.